# Keep executing SQL queries after Exception

Tags: java, loops, exception

Hello I am making an app to insert data into a database from a text file. Right now my code inserts the information correctly, but when there is an error in a data field, the program stops and does not insert the rest of the information. It also logs the error using log4j but will not keep executing. How could I make it so after it reads the error, it just logs the error and keeps going? This is what I have so far. I am pretty sure I have to put a loop somewhere but when I do it gives me an error or does something I do not want.

```
 System.out.println("create jdbc connection using properties file");

            Connection con = null;


            // use try becuase it tends to fail sometimes and we want error messages

            try {

                //load properties file we have created
                Properties prop = loadPropertiesFile();

                //declare vars and get the properties at the same time
                String driverClass = prop.getProperty("SQLSERVERJDBC.driver");

                // have to instance driver
                Class.forName(driverClass).newInstance();


                // make connection object using the previous things as parameters

            try{
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://"+txtuserinputhost.getText()+":"+txtuserinputport.getText()+";DatabaseName=FRONTMC", txtuserinputuser.getText(), txtuserinputpassword.getText());
            }catch(SQLException errorid){

                logger.error("ERROR CREDENCIALES");

                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        errorcon();
                        }   
                    }

                ).start();
            }





                //this if is to verify the connection
                if (con != null) {
                    System.out.println("connection created successfully using properties file");


                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                            "C:\\Users\\darroyo\\Documents\\pruebasx.txt"));

                    ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    // Read line from file.


                    try{
                    while (true) {
                        String line = reader.readLine();
                        if (line == null) {

                            break;
                        }
                        // Split line on space.
                        String[] parts = line.split("");
                        //part in parts
                        for (String part : parts) {

                            //part is the element in this case each fix tag with value
                            array1.add(part);

                        }
                        String query = " insert into FRONTMC.HECHO (folio_hecho, folio_orden, emisora, serie,"
                                + "clave_sentido, titulos_hecho, precio, importe, liquidacion, contraparte, id_estatus, isin, contrato,"
                                + "secondary_exec_id, exec_id, F11_ClOrdID, fecha_recepcion, fecha_sentra)"
                                    + " values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,convert(varchar(30),cast(? as datetime),120),convert(varchar(30),cast(? as datetime),120))";

                                  // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
                                  PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);


                                  for(int counter =0; counter< array1.size();counter++){
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("37=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (1, array1.get(counter).substring(3));

                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("37=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (2, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                      }

                                      // change emisora and serie to 48 with bd
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("49=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (3, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                      }

                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("447=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (4, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("54=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (5, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("32=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (6, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("31=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (7, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("381=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (8, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("63=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (9, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("448=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (10, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("150=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (11, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("48=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (12, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 2).equals("1=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (13, array1.get(counter).substring(2));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 4).equals("527=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (14, array1.get(counter).substring(4));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("17=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (15, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("11=")){
                                          preparedStmt.setString (16, array1.get(counter).substring(3));
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("52=")){

                                          String date = array1.get(counter).substring(3);

                                            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                                            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                            String ds2 = sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(date));
                                            String x = date.substring(9, 21);
                                            String newfecha1 = ds2+" "+x;


                                          preparedStmt.setString (17, newfecha1);
                                      }
                                      if(array1.get(counter).substring(0, 3).equals("52=")){

                                          String date = array1.get(counter).substring(3);

                                            SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                                            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                                            String ds2 = sdf2.format(sdf1.parse(date));
                                            String x = date.substring(9, 21);
                                            String newfecha1 = ds2+" "+x;


                                          preparedStmt.setString (18, newfecha1);
                                      }



                                  }

                                  // execute the preparedstatement

                                  try{
                                  preparedStmt.execute();
                                  }catch(SQLException inserterr){
                                      inserterr.printStackTrace();
                                  }


                    }

                    System.out.println(array1);


                    reader.close();
                    }catch(Exception tryerror){
                        System.out.println("Error en dato");
                    }
                    //creating the statement(should check to use prepared statement in the future

                    // fecha recp y fecha sentra in query and for and ? and order



                              //notifies you that it was completed
                    System.out.println("insert complete");



                    //Read number of lines
                      File file = new File("C:\\Users\\darroyo\\Documents\\pruebasx.txt");
                      LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));
                      lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                      int lines = lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
                      lineNumberReader.close();


                    countermsjinsertados.setText(Integer.toString(lines));


                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            exitomsj();
                            }   
                        }

                    ).start();

                }







                else {
                    System.out.println(" unable to create connection");


                }



                // loop to check the digits ex. for() array.1get(counter).substring(0,3).equals("23=")

                //error messages
                //ERROR CREDENCIALES
            }catch (SQLException eb) {

                System.out.println("error");
                logger.error("ERROR DATOS");


                new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        errorcon2();
                        }   
                    }

                ).start();

            } 

            //ERROR MESSAGE FECHA just get line number
            catch (Exception eb) {


                eb.printStackTrace();

            } finally {

                try {
                    if (con != null) {
                        con.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }

            }



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The pseudocode structure you want is:

```
while(there is more data to process) {
    try {
        do the work, maybe throw an exception
    } catch (exceptions) {
        log the error
        if the exception is fatal, rethrow
    }
}
```

The `try-catch` block deals with exceptions occurring when processing an item.

In the `catch` block, if you decide that the exception is serious enough to cancel the entire process (for example, the database connection failed making it meaningless to continue), you throw a new exception wrapping the original one. Since you're outside the `try` this new exception will bubble up to the enclosing context and you can deal with it there or let it terminate the process.

If the exception is "recoverable" in the sense that you can continue processing additional items, the code structure above will do exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

As I understand it, you want your program to do something regardless of whether or not an exception is thrown.

In that case, try putting that code in a finally block, which does exactly that.

If this isn't what you wanted to do, please let me know.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, so the whole block would go in a finally or just the execution of the prepared statement?

Comment: I would only put the code in the finally block that I would want executed no matter what. If your "prepared statement" meets that definition, then I would put only that statement in the block.

Comment: That is not what `finally` blocks are for.  If you put all the code in `finally`, what do you do if that code throws an exception?